# Extract only first line in each cell in google sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, newline, text-extraction

I want to extract only the first line of text in each cell. (Sorry for screenshots I can't figure out another way to illustrate). [image]

I am using this formula in the `Company` column to find the new-line character and extract the text to the left of it:

`=LEFT(G2,Find(Char(10),G2))`

If I manually go through and highlight the entire cell in the `Description` column then hit `enter` it will add a newline character after the text in the first line but otherwise there is no newline character present. Hence the `#VALUE` error. Any ideas how to bulk insert a newline character into every cell so the existing function will work? Open to other solutions as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do:

```
=LEFT(G2&CHAR(10), FIND(CHAR(10), G2&CHAR(10)))
```

---

### update 1:

delete everything in column A and use this in A1:

```
={"Company"; INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "(.+)\n"), B2:B))}
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
={"Company"; INDEX(TRIM(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
 REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(\d+)", CHAR(10)&"$1"), "(.+)\n"), B2:B)))}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you! Sorry don't know why I didn't think of that. Here is a sheet with sample  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RX25IBYyDwQEQD8AeCjjnoC5U5Cka2dlfQAPhHoIICU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I was clear with what I'm try to do. My apologies. I only want to extract the company name out of each cell in the description column. in cell A5 in the screenshot I would only want "SERVPRO of Birmingham" and not the address.

Comment: Thank you so much! This will take me a while to figure out what you did here! Looks great!

Comment: @JustinBenfit I searched for first number and inserted new line in front of that number. then I extracted everything before the new line

Comment: not all heroes wear a cape! Wait! By the avatar, I'm not sure this one does!

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, Char(10)),LEFT(A1,Find(Char(10),A1)-1),A1)
```

Pseudo code:

```
if \newline_char is found in A1:    # REGEXMATCH(A1, Char(10)):
    return first line of cell excluding \newline_char # LEFT(A1,Find(Char(10),A1)-1)
else:
    return A1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the the position of char that goes to the next line `CHAR(10)` with the formula `FIND()`.

Then with `Mid()`, you select the substring you need to get line1 and line2.

here you have the full example
[image]

```
=find(CHAR(10) ; A2)   // Position of the char that goes to the next line
=mid(A2 ; 1 ; C2 -1)   // First Line
=mid(A2 ; C2 ; 999999) // Second Line
```